How can I define in GitLab that specific jobs must pass (but not all of them) in a pipeline triggered by Jenkins?
I have jenkins jobs running and update their status on my GitLab repository to relevant merge requests.
This opens a pipeline on a merge request, and all jobs reported from Jenkins are there.
In GitLab Merge Request settings there is an option to request that all pipelines must pass.
But I want to be specific and mention which jobs must pass since not ALL jobs in the pipeline must pass.
How can I do that without using a yml file (since I don't have one and I prefer not to use one)?
As an example, in GitHub under branch protection rules, it is easy to just list the jobs that are "required" and those are the ones that must pass. I would just like to know where in the GitLab settings this can be done in a similar way.
Update:
Based on the answer that referred to this link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/status_checks.html#view-the-status-checks-on-a-project there is a way to define this from the GitLab UI (so it seems). However, this is available only to Ultimate Tier and not to basic users.
Is there any other way to do this that can be managed not from the Ultimate Tier? I am willing to do this with a yml file if needed.


Within each project’s settings, you can see a list of status check
services added to the project:
On the left sidebar, select Search or go to and find your project.
Select Settings > Merge requests. Scroll down to Status checks. Status
checks list
This list shows the service name, API URL, targeted branch, and HMAC
authentication status. It also provides actions to allow you to
create, edit, or remove status checks.

Gitlab Documentation
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/status_checks.html#view-the-status-checks-on-a-project
EDIT
I saw your update. I don't know if this fits totally your requirements.
If status check does not work, you can use add a stage in the end of your pipeline that approve the merge using a service account in case of success. Then, you can set on you repository's configuration your service's account approval as a necessary merge condition.

Thanks  a lot! Although, I followed these instructions and the phrase "Status Check" doesn't appear anywhere on the page under settings->Merge Reqeusts

@EyalGerber saw your update, you can see my edit. It's not the best solution but it will require you having a service account, sending some curl command to the Gitlab API and configuring you merge checks.

perhaps you can provide more thorough details on how to do this exactly. It is not quite clear what you mean.

@Eyal have look here https://github.com/pepakriz/gitlab-merger-bot

This is not good because it launched manual jobs automatically but in my case the jobs are launched from Jenkins independently from GitLab.

please could you elaborate your answer a little bit more so that I can award you the bounty?

@EyalGerber yes ofc. It's not very complicated. In the end of your pipeline, you can add a step where a bot account approves the PR if everything goes well using the Gitlab API.
Hence, in the merge checks, you must be sure that the bot account approved the PR (thus the build was successful). The problem with this solution is scalability.
